# What's wrong when building phonegap project?

Tags: java, android, node.js, cordova

I'm trying to build android project with the latest phonegap (3.3, http://phonegap.com/install/) with the node command manager - npm, but I get an error. What's wrong?

Here is the error message:

```
 C:\...\Documents\PHONEGAP\my-app>phonegap run android
[phonegap] detecting Android SDK environment...
[phonegap] using the local environment
[phonegap] adding the Android platform...
   [error] An error occured during creation of android sub-project.

C:\...\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.3.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error: An error occurred while listing Android targets
    at C:\...\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.3.0\bin\lib\check_reqs.js:8
7:29
    at _rejected (C:\...\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.3.0\bin\node_mod
ules\q\q.js:808:24)
    at C:\...\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.3.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js
:834:30
    at Promise.when (C:\...\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.3.0\bin\node_
modules\q\q.js:1079:31)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\...\.cordova\lib\android\cord
ova\3.3.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:752:41)
    at C:\...\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.3.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js
:574:44
    at flush (C:\...\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.3.0\bin\node_modules
\q\q.js:108:17)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

Comment: have you installed android sdk 19?

Comment: Yes actually, I'll check which stuff I've installed on Android SDK

Comment: When I say sdk 19 I mean launch the sdk manager and install the component "SDK Platform" for API 19. Phonegap 3.3 configures target sdk 19. If you had not sdk 19 installed when you first launched "phonegap run android", try removing the platforms/android folder before retesting.

Comment: Maybe I should reinstall Phonegap through node then?

Comment: no, no need, the issue happens when phonegap adds the android target to the project, not at phonegap installation

Answer (score -1):

If you have eclipse for android development, you can use that with the downloaded .js file of cordova.js to locally build your android app with phonegap or use any other web editor and use online build for your application. Hope this helps.